# Make ggplot displays less data points on axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following dataset named `unemploymentDataByRegion`

```
# A tibble: 66 × 3
   Year  Region                                      Unemployment
   <chr> <chr>                                       <chr>       
 1 2020  Red River Delta                             2.05        
 2 NA    Northern midlands and mountain areas        1.06        
 3 NA    North Central area and Central coastal area 3.16        
 4 NA    Central Highlands                           1.66        
 5 NA    South  East                                 3.23        
 6 NA    Mekong River Delta                          2.82        
 7 2019  Red River Delta                             1.82        
 8 NA    Northern midlands and mountain areas        1.29        
 9 NA    North Central area and Central coastal area 2.47        
10 NA    Central Highlands                           1.37        
# … with 56 more rows
```

Which displays data of unemployment rate for 6 regions from 2010 to 2020. I plotted the data via `ggplot`

```
ggplot(data = unemploymentDataByRegion, aes(x = Region, y = Unemployment,group=Region)) + 
    geom_boxplot() +
    ggtitle("Distribution of Unemployment from 2010-2020") +
    coord_flip()
```

However, the `Unemployment` statistics look packed together, which isn't pretty

[image]

Is there any way to custom the range for `Unemployment`, making it display less values?

Comment: Perhaps try changing `aes(x = Region, y = Unemployment,group=Region)` to `aes(x = Region, y = as.numeric(Unemployment), group=Region)`

Comment: Yes, your `Unemployment` column is stored as text ("character", aka `chr`) data, so the way it's plotting is alphabetical, has axis text for every unique number, is not to scale, and possibly isn't even in numeric order (e.g. 10.1 would come before 9.0). I'd suggest fixing that in the source table so that you can plot and do calculations with it more easily. `unemploymentDataByRegion$Unemployment = as.numeric(unemploymentDataByRegion$Unemployment)`

Comment: Even better would be to fix the code that is reading in the data, so it never gets converted into character in the first place.